# onChipAdd and onChipDelete not calling function

Tags: javascript, materialize

I don't know why as I'm following the official documentation but the functions of onChipAdd and onChipDelete are not called when adding and deleting chips.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.chips');
  var instances = M.Chips.init(elems, {
    placeholder: 'Entrer un filtre',
    secondaryPlaceholder: '+Filtre',
    autocompleteOptions: {
      data: {
        {% for tag in tags %}
        {{ tag }}: null,
        {% endfor %}
      },
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 1
    },
    onChipAdd: function (e, data) { console.log("test") },
    onChipDelete: function (e, data) { console.log("test") }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the answer on the chat with the team:

```
function chipAddCallback() {
  const lastTagAdded = this.chipsData[this.chipsData.length - 1].tag;
  const message = `"${lastTagAdded}" Chip added!`;
  console.log(message);
}
function chipDeleteCallback() {
  console.log("Chip Deleted!");
}
function init() {
  $(".chips").chips({
    placeholder: "Entrer un filtre",
    secondaryPlaceholder: "+Filtre",
    onChipAdd: chipAddCallback,
    onChipDelete: chipDeleteCallback,
    autocompleteOptions: {
      data: {
        {% for tag in tags %}
        {{ tag }}: null,
        {% endfor %}
      },
      limit: Infinity,
      minLength: 1
    }
  });
}
$(init);
```

I don't know why this beaviour for calling the init is the good one, but it's working

Answer (score 0):

You've to use `options` like this to call the callback functions of chips.

```
<div class="chips"></div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var options = {
            onChipAdd() {
                console.log("added");
            },
            onChipSelect() {
                console.log("Selected");
            },
            onChipDelete() {
                console.log("Deleted");
            },
            placeholder: 'Entrer un filtre',
            secondaryPlaceholder: '+Filtre',
            autocompleteOptions: {
                data: {
                    'Apple': null,
                    'Microsoft': null,
                    'Google': null
                },
                limit: Infinity,
                minLength: 1
            }
        }
        var elems = document.querySelector('.chips');
        var instances = M.Chips.init(elems, options);
    });
</script>
```

[image: Program - gif]

Comment: Still not working...

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var options = {
placeholder: 'Entrer un filtre',
secondaryPlaceholder: '+Filtre',
autocompleteOptions: {
data: {
{% for tag in tags %}
{{ tag }}: null,
{% endfor %}
},
limit: Infinity,
minLength: 1
},
onChipAdd() {
console.log("added");
},
onChipDelete() {
console.log("deleted");
}
}
var elems = document.querySelector('.chips');
var instances = M.Chips.init(elems, options);
});`

Comment: @Altiire, Can you check it now?

Comment: Hum, a bit buggy but "added" is showing on Apple and Microsoft :)

Comment: I can't delete an autocompleted chip

Comment: That's strange, I can delete the autocomplete chips and "added" is being shown for every chip.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine for me.  I modified Germa's answer above a little bit.  The only thing different is that onChipAdd, onChipSelect and onChipDelete are arrow functions.  Check it out and give it a try for yourself.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        let elems = document.querySelector('.chips');
        let options = {
           onChipAdd: () => console.log("added"),
           onChipSelect: () => console.log("Selected"),
           onChipDelete: () => console.log("Deleted"),
           placeholder: 'Entrer un filtre',
           secondaryPlaceholder: '+ filtre',
           autocompleteOptions: {
              data: {
                 'Apple': null,
                 'Microsoft': null,
                 'Google': null
              },
              limit: Infinity,
              minLength: 1
           }
        }
        let instances = M.Chips.init(elems, options);
     });
```